# Why is node save extremely slow with two or more tags after migrating tags and restoring from backup?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, migrations

**The problem**
Saving a node with one tag saves normally. With two or more, the save takes upwards of 40 seconds.
The problem only occurs after migrating in a set of tags from csv, then creating a mysqldump backup of the database and restoring the database.

**Migration Details**
4,457 tags were migrated
No errors
The "csv" file is tab separated... so really TSV
The tsv file has two fields only: OldTID and name
The migrated tags are flat: no hierarchy

**Configuration Details**
Drupal 9.4.7 fresh install via Composer, standard profile
Default theme (Olivero)
Standard install modules only, except for these:

- migration
- migrate_plus
- migrate_tools
- migrate_source_csv

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 lts
Database server: 10.6.7-MariaDB-2ubuntu1.1 - Ubuntu 22.04
Webserver: nginx 1.18.0
PHP: 8.1.2

**Steps to reproduce**

- Install Drupal via Composer: 9.4.7 Standard profile
- No advanced options during install
- Add one field to tags taxonomy: field_old_id
- Install drush via Composer (11.2.1)
- Install migrate_plus, migrate_tools, migrate source csv

  - Import the config for tags.yml
  - Run migration from drush, importing 4457 tags, flat
  - Create test node, selecting two tags: save is normal, < 2 seconds
  - *Backup db* using command line mysqldump
  - Create new db
  - *Restore db* using command line mysql dbname < dumpfile.sql, no changes to codebase
  - Test resave of the same node (2 tags): slow, >40 seconds
  - Test save with one tag: normal, < 2 seconds

**The migration yaml config**

```
uuid: 1bcec3e7-0a49-4473-87a2-6dca09b91abax-tags
id: tags
label: Import tags from tsv to taxonomy
migration_group: taxonomy
source:
  plugin: 'csv'
  path: '/srv/imports/tags.tab'
  delimiter: "\t"
  enclosure: '"'
  header_offset: null
  ids: [OldTID]
  fields:
    0:
      name: OldTID
      label: 'Old tag ID'
    1:
      name: name
      label: 'Tagname'

process:
  name: name
  field_old_id: OldTID
destination:
  plugin: entity:taxonomy_term
  default_bundle: tags
```

Comment: Have you profiled the PHP and looked into the slow query log?

Comment: Yes this problem is likely to be localised to your environment, so profiling to find out where the time is being spent is pretty much essential to start the debugging process

Comment: Could this be an issue with the version of MariaDB?

Comment: New to profiling. Any tools to recommend?  Slow query log: should have thought of that. Will take a look.

Comment: I can tell you we encountered a similar issue in regards to Paragraphs on MariaDB 10.4. When downgrading to 10.3, this particular issue went away. It sounds very close to how you describe it. Can you try another version of MariaDB or just MySQL to rule that out?

Comment: Thanks. It may be a while before I can test old Maria/vanilla MySQL. This is interesting from slow query log: 
# Thread_id: 31  Schema: si2dev  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 50.030617  Lock_time: 0.000859  Rows_sent: 2  Rows_examined: 20827776
# Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 195  
Is that query time 50 seconds... and 20 million rows?

Comment: The rest of that query:  SET timestamp=1664737272;
  SELECT "base_table"."revision_id" AS "revision_id", "base_table"."tid" AS "tid"
  FROM
"taxonomy_term_data" "base_table"
  INNER JOIN "taxonomy_term_field_data" "taxonomy_term_field_data"   ON "taxonomy_term_field_d   WHERE ("taxonomy_term_field_data"."vid" IN ('tags')) AND ("taxonomy_term_field_data"."tid"

Comment: Tested on another server: MariaDB 10.3.34, Ubuntu 20.04, PHP7.4.3 - No slow save after migrating, dumping, restoring, saving with multiple tags.    Unfortunately, I don't have an environment with same PHP, but most likely we're looking at something going on in MariaDB>10.3.34.

Comment: I would bet on it being MariaDB.

Comment: Yep. I couldn't downgrade, but could upgrade. The problem no longer occurs in 10.8.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a *complete* answer, because we still don't know what in particular misbehaved and why.
But the problem has something to do with that version of MariaDB.

After adding the repository, etc., I was able to upgrade the MariaDB to 10.8.5.

Following the set of steps above, the problem no longer occurs.

Comment: It is as like as not due to the MariaDB runtime configuration or compiled-in defaults differing between versions as it is an actual bug.

Comment: I've witnessed the same thing with Paragraphs when upgrading (via Pantheon) from Maria 10.1 to 10.4. We had to downgrade to 10.3. It has something to do with how Maria is calculating or caching rows where it makes poor optimizations or something of that nature.

Comment: Tested also in standard MySQL. Server version: 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.22.04.1    The slow node save (after import, mysqldump, restore, with 2 or more tags on the node) also does not occur in this environment.